# How to choose between two words using JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sentence example: `I am just one man` I', trying to capture `am just on` with the following regex, but it also captures `I` which is not what I need.

```
(?=I).*(?= man)
```

The result is: `I am just one`

I don't want extra capturing groups, only the full match which should be `am just one`.

Comment: change the first positive lookahead to a negative (?!I).

Comment: Thanks… I'm trying to learn Regex

Comment: Why are there so many downvotes? Is the question wrong or something?

Comment: [mcve] is your answer. Please put the regex in the question itself, not a screenshot of regex101.com. And provide more explanation about what you want. I'll edit your question to teach you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the first positive lookahead to a negative (?!I). This won't capture `I`

```
(?!I).*(?= one)
```

By saying look and match anything except `I`

```
(?=[^I ]).*(?= man)
```